# How to change SourceTree theme to dark

Tags: interface, themes

I have dark theme enabled in Windows + newest version of SourceTree 2.3.5.0 and it's still destroying my sight with bright theme.

Any clue how to switch please?

Thank You!

Kind regards

Bryan

[windows settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ1sr.jpg)

[source tree missing settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHsyP.jpg)

Comment: It was implement in ST 4+ according to [this issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-6921?focusedCommentId=2294959&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2294959). It does look very nice: [ST dark mode screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTeFv.png).

Answer (score 1):

Now, you can set the **dark theme of SourceTree**. Download its latest version from [this site](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), as per your OS.

**On Windows**

When installed open it, go to `Tools > Options > General > Theme`, then select `Dark` from dropdown menu.
[image]

**On Mac**

While on Mac, you have to go to `View > Appearance > Dark Mode`